# getElementByClassName Not Returning Results

Tags: javascript

My `getElementByClassName()` isn't returning any results, I had it set to `getElementById()`, but I can't use the `Id` since the same function will need to apply to seven links. I have filled in all the information on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew9Ve/2/)

The javascript looks like:

```
var myBoxWidth = 0;
var myBoxWidth2 = 0;

// show
function show() {
    var myBox = document.getElementByClassName('box');  
    var myContent = document.getElementByClassName('content');
    myContent.style.display = 'inline';
    myBox.style.width = myBoxWidth + '%';  
    if(myBoxWidth < 80) {  
        myBoxWidth += 20;
        setTimeout(show,55);
    }
}

// hide
function hide() {
    var myBox = document.getElementByClassName('box');
    var myContent = document.getElementByClassName('content');
    myContent.style.display = 'none';
    var currentWidthVal = parseInt(myBox.style.width,10);
    if(myBoxWidth2 < currentWidthVal) {  
        setTimeout(hide,55);
        myBox.style.width = currentWidthVal =  currentWidthVal - 20 + '%';
        myBoxWidth = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like `NodeList` / `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: just curious... why aren't you using jQuery?

Comment: This is for a particular project that has to specifically use JavaScript or I would be using jQuery, jQuery is more of my comfort zone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is no such `getElementByClassName()`. Try [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

### Update

`document.getElementsByClassName('..')` returns a set of elements while your code is written with expectation that it'll return single element. You could change that part to

```
var myContent = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

var num = myContent.length;

for(var x=0; x < num; x++){
    myContent[x].style.display = 'block'; //or whatever style you've in your original code 
}
```

Comment: And note that `getElementsByClassName()`, as the plural in the name implies, returns a list of elements, not a single element. This is because classes, unlike ID's, aren't unique.

Comment: Ok, so this would have to apply to an array? is it possible to set up the page content in an array and pull the information that way?

Comment: You'll have to iterate over the list that `getElementsByClassName()` returns. I assumed you could take it on form there :) If you want to work with first found elements then you could probably use `var myContent = document.getElementByClassName('content')[0];`

Comment: I'm kinda new to useing the getElementsByClassName() what do you mean iterate, I keep seeing this everywhere without any expamples

Comment: I'm still not sure how to include the class box as well

Comment: Adding var myContent = document.getElementByClassName('content');

var num = myContent.length;

for(var x=0; x < num; x++){
    myContent[x].style.display = 'block';
}

did return the contents I had set, but box still isn't working no matter what I try to code in. Shouldn't the code run similarly to the Id?

Comment: you're still using `document.getElementByClassName('content')` because of a typo in my update after which I had to move away from the machine. Make sure it is `var myContent = document.getElementsByClassName('content');` :) And the `...style='block'` is there just for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

It is getElementsByClassName instead of getElementByClassName. I would also recommend using jQuery or some sort of js framework.